# Detect if HTML was edited

Tags: javascript, web, firebug

Is it possible to detect if - let's say - someone uses firebug to change parts of the website that's been loaded.

E.g. I got `<a href="javascript:myfunc('hello')">` and someone changes that to `<a href="javascript:myfunc('NOThello')">`. Can I immediately detect this change somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: Use server side checks instead of relying on client security.

Comment: Why care if something not returned to the server is changed. I may want text larger or a different font color

Comment: I commented to jfriend00's answer. I'm just curious about that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, right, you're just curious about how to do that!

I can't reproduce your [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471683/detect-if-html-was-edited#comment32417892_21471704), but here are the options I see:

- using a recursive setTimeout or setInterval checking when the element has been altered, but that is highly slow and ugly
- using [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), and unset the changes

Florent

Comment: Okay that is intersting. Using Internet Explorer this didn't change a thing. Using Chrome all of a sudden e.g. `onclick="STD.Forum.rate('35635693',1, 1,this, true);"` is not there anymore. Well yes a timeout wouldn't be such a nice way. It also would either be to slow or cost too much resources. And yes :D I am just curious. I think I am past that point where I want to write harmful code. But thanks for that mutation observers. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot.

You could obviously write code to check to see if something was the way you wanted it to be, but guess what?  People could change that very code to bypass the detection.  Web pages are complete insecure.  You cannot trust anything in them.  They can be easily altered - any part of them can be altered including HTML, javascript, etc...  And, using debuggers is not the only way to alter web pages - there are many different techniques including things like active proxies.

You MUST verify and check on the server anything that is being submitted to a server because you simply cannot trust its origin.  For example, people use client-side javascript to validate data that is entered into forms all the time, but this is ONLY done to improve the user experience if something is entered incorrectly (so you can more easily tell the user something is wrong BEFORE the data is submitted to the server).  All validation checking must also be done on the server to make sure that only valid data gets into your server.

Comment: Well yes, this is what I thought. Then I tried to manipulate just for fun the upvote button for a comment of an online newspaper. The second I was changing part of the code it vanished. You can try it yourself. Goto http://derstandard.at/1389858663917/Wir-haben-jetzt-Zeit-dass-wir-aussortieren and change e.g. anything of a button: `<a class="std-button rate p" title="Sehr lesenswert" rel="nofollow" onclick="STD.Forum.rate('35635693',1, 1,this, true);">+</a>`. Using Chrome this did not work that's why I was wondering how this could be possible.

Comment: @StefanFalk - I'm not sure how you were changing it, but I was able to  change a std-button with no problem in Chrome.  If I tried to edit the onclick code, the edit did not take in Chrome, but if I removed the onclick attribute and then added a different one, the edit worked.  This is just some limitation in Chrome's ability to edit things.